# Contar Operaciones repetidas SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Buen día estimados, estoy realizando una consulta en SQL server, en donde tengo una tabla de movimientos en donde lo que quiero realizar es lo siguiente.

Por ejemplo
tengo los tipos de operaciones:
21
**12
12
12**
21
16
29
12
8
12

Pero únicamente me gustaría saber la cantidad de veces que se repite la operación 12 de forma seguida sin que haya otro tipo de operación de por medio.

si alguien pudiera apoyarme se lo agradecería mucho, ya he intentado varias veces pero no logro llegar al resultado que necesito.

he probado con el siguiente query.

```
**select Pedido, count(TipoOperacion) as Cantidad from Movimientos
where TipoOperacion=12**
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! defini seguidas, porque para que algo este seguido en sql, tiene que haber un order by, cosa que en tu consulta no pusiste...ç

Comment: Necesitamos la estructura de la tabla con datos de prueba e indicación de cual será la columna o conjunto de columnas que indiquen el orden de las filas.

Comment: @LuisCazares esta es la estructura de la tabla:  **SELECT No_Pedido,
 No_Tienda,
 Tipo_Operacion,
Fecha_Operacion,
 Importe,
FROM MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO** lo que quiero saber es lo siguiente:  por ejemplo en el pedido 7872 de la sucursal 2837 se realizaron las siguientes operaciones: 1 |TiOp =|12, fecha=01/03|, 2 |TiOp =|12, fecha=07/03|, 3 |TiOp =|12, fecha=14/03|, 4  |TiOp =|07, fecha=21/03|, 5  |TiOp =|12, fecha=28/03|, 6  |TiOp =|04, fecha=04/04|. necesito cuantas veces se repite la operación 12 sin que haya otra operación de por medio. el resultado que espero seria 3 veces.  gracias.

Comment: intentaste con CASE;  select case count(quantity )when quantity = 12 then 0
end,
from "MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO" ;

Comment: @pperez gracias, lo intente pero me da error en la consulta.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para poner los detalles. En los comentarios no se lee correctamente.

Comment: @Rony y el with cte no te sirve [aqui](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7cc73322fdb00a91c1b76afb02edbcaa) la funcion agrupa ciertos criterios.

Comment: @pperez  select No_Pedido, No_Tienda, Fecha_Operacion, Tipo_Operacion, 1 as Num
 into #Secuencia
 from MOVIMIENTO_PEDIDO

select No_Pedido, No_Tienda, Fecha_Operacion, Tipo_Operacion, 
case when Tipo_Operacion=LAG(Tipo_Operacion) over (order by Fecha_Operacion) then num +1 
 else 1 end as Cantidad_Veces_Repetidas
from #Secuencia    intente con este query, sin embargo, no me da el resultado esperado, ya que solo me llega sumando hasta 2 y si hay mas numeros repetidos consecutivos va colocando nada mas el dos pero no me lo sigue sumando.